# ¿Porque no se pueden usar doubles en un vector3?

Tags: unity3d, unity, double

Estoy programando un vehículo que se mueve y a la hora de hacer un Translate a su componente Transform no me deja usar doubles ni dentro, ni multiplicando el vector por 0.2, por ejemplo. Mi vehículo se mueve muy rápido incluso usando valores pequeños. Además me sorprende que no se pueda por una cuestión de precisión matemática. Hay algo que no estoy viendo que se pueda hacer? Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, soy recién llegado al mundo de Unity.

Comment: Podes colocar el codigo y el error que te da?

Answer (score 0):

No puedes  utilizar doubles en un Vector3, debes utilizar floats en ese caso, si tu vehiculo se mueve muy rapido puede ser porque estes realizando el codigo en la funciona void update() , que se ejecuta una vez por cada frame  probablemente este sea tu problema , una solucion seria multiplicarlo por un Time.deltatime , esto haria que el movimiento se realizara cada segundo y no cada frame un ejemplo

transform.Translate((Vector3 * Time.deltaTime * VariableDeVelocidad );

en vector 3, lo ajustas los ejes de movimiento un ejemplo seria (0,1,0) se moveria hacia arriba a la velocidad  que tome la VariableDeVelocidad.